# How to change Chrome homepage with a bat file?

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, browser, cmd

I am trying to make a bat file to change the chrome's homepage.
cd %homepath%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
But I don't know the next step.

Answer (score 1):

**In Google chrome:**

chrome settings are in %USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data.ChromotingConfig.json and are a little bit encrypted.

but you can do a workaround like by just pasting following javascript into the "Home Page" pref field (under your Chrome options) and it works as expected when clicking the "Home" button.

```
javascript:(function(){ window.location.href='http://www.google.com/';})();
```