# chrome homepage changer script

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file

I've found this:

> In Google chrome:
>
> chrome settings are in %USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application
>   Data\Google\Chrome\User Data.ChromotingConfig.json and are a little
>   bit encrypted.
>
> but you can do a workaround like by just pasting following javascript
>   into the "Home Page" pref field (under your Chrome options) and it
>   works as expected when clicking the "Home" button.
>
> javascript:(function(){
>   window.location.href='http://www.google.com/';})();

How to pasting javascript code to Chrome? How to use this workaround from batch file or c# code?

Thanks

Comment: open `console` of chrome using `F12` key and type the same script

Comment: Why don't you set that value by making the changes in registry?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch file to set homepage in all browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763171/batch-file-to-set-homepage-in-all-browsers)

Comment: And also duplicate of [How to change Chrome homepage with a bat file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623710/how-to-change-chrome-homepage-with-a-bat-file) And the users of Chrome as all other browsers do not like it when a visited page or a batch file modifies the start page. This is a user setting and no application or web page should manipulate silently browser settings. So do not expect any useful answer here on Stack Overflow as most of us don't like what you try.